# Sharepoint / SSRS subscriptions intermittently not emailing

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs

I am running MOSS with SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services in integrated mode. There are a number of reports that are generated and then output emailed through SharePoint's subscriptions. Sporadically all subscriptions will fail to email with the error message of "Failure sending mail: Report Server has encountered a SharePoint error."

Can any one shed any light as to why this is occuring and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Does the error returns an error code? Or maybe more details on the error? Did you check the log on the report server?

Comment: Have you turned on verbose logging on the sharepoint server? It may show the error there. Note though that logging verbosely may impact the performance of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the status of your subscriptions and when they last executed, you can perform a query: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/sqlserverpedia/~3/O78C3knsUO0/

Comment: This link is dead. Could you update your answer please?